# modifier key combination input

Tags: c#, silverlight, richtextbox

I'm working on my own text editor in silverlight. I made different functions to make text in a richtextbox bold, italic or underlined. I want the functions to be run also when the user presses the combinations ctrl-B, ctrl-U, ctrl-I.

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect user input with the KeyDown event of a RichTextBox. Then you can simply check for the right combination of key and modifier in that event handler and call your functions there:

```
private void MyRTB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.B) 
            {
                MakeBold();
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.I)
            {
                MakeItalic();
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.U)
            {
                Underline();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I'll accept this as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

The KeyDown event handler will work.  A slightly improved version is to use the KeyDownTrigger from the Blend SDK.  Your XAML would then look something like this:

```
<RichTextBox>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:KeyDownTrigger Modifiers="Control" Key="B">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MakeBold}" />
    </i:KeyDownTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</RichTextBox>
```

where MakeBold is exposed as an ICommand on your view model.  This explicitly puts all of your keyboard interactions into your XAML where it belongs rather than in random bits of code.